want to establish two way connection between Ubuntu & Fortigate via 'Cloud' interface in GNS3 gui
I wanna establish duplex connection between Ubuntu & Fortigate via 'Cloud' interface in GNS3 gui
I'm unable to connect FortiGate (which is installed in GNS3 VM) to my host network. I want to use host-only or bridged adapter so that there will be duplex connection. NAT is working but I'm unable to make inbound connection to FortiGate (like accessing web-ui of FortiGate). I have done lots of troubleshooting but not working. Please anyone can help me. 
Host OS (Physical machine) > Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Hypervisor for GNS3 VM > VirtualBox 6.1
GNS3 VM (Server) 2.2.50
FortiGate v7.0.9
https is allowed on Fortigate interface
this is newly installed firewall and there is no conflicting policies
already tested with diff browser and even in incognito mode
Here is the all interface configuration of FortiGate
'FortiGate7.0.9-1'
FortiGate-VM64-KVM # show system interface config system interface
edit "port1"
set vdom "root"
set ip 192.168.56.110 255.255.255.0 set allowaccess ping https ssh http 
set type physical
set snmp-index 1
next
edit "naf.root"
set vdom "root"
set type tunnel
set src-check disable
set snmp-index 2
edit "12t.root"
next
set vdom "root"
set type tunnel
set snmp-index 3
edit "ssl.root"
next
set vdom "root"
set type tunnel
set alias "SSL VPN interface"
set snmp-index 4
edit "fortilink"
set vdom "root"
set fortilink enable
set ip 10.255.1.1 255.255.255.0
set allowaccess ping fabric
set type aggregate
set lldp-reception enable
set lldp-transmission enable set snmp-index 5'






"Duplex" like in LACP LAG? L3 multi-pathing? Or just a full-duplex link? We cannot help you with the host configuration, but you need to show us the Fortigate one.

By 'duplex' I mean 'two-way communication between Ubuntu and FortiGate'

All network links are 'duplex' in that sense.

but I'm unable to access fortigate web-gui on my host network (Ubuntu), pls help

All appliances are running in GNS3 VM

Please add the configurations in text format, using the editor's {} preformat option. Do not use screenshots. And we cannot help you with your hypervisor configuration here.
